# How to fix OpenSSL Padding Oracle vulnerability (CVE-2016-2107) for nginx on debian jessie?

Tags: nginx, debian, openssl

As far as i understood, it should be sufficient to upgrade openssl (done a long time ago, now installed all available updates again (no openssl there)) and restart nginx.
I even tried to stop nginx fully (verified it with `ps`) and start it again.

But ssllabs still tells me, that i am vulnerable. What else do i need to do, or what can be causing that its still vulnerable?

versions:

```
ii  nginx                              1.9.10-1                          all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server
ii  nginx-common                       1.9.10-1                          all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server - common files
ii  nginx-full                         1.9.10-1                          amd64        nginx web/proxy server (standard version)
ii  openssl                            1.0.1t-1+deb8u2                   amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - cryptographic utility

ii  libssl-dev:amd64                   1.0.1t-1+deb8u2                   amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
ii  libssl-doc                         1.0.1t-1+deb8u2                   all          Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development documentation
ii  libssl1.0.0:amd64                  1.0.1t-1+deb8u2                   amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
ii  libssl1.0.2:amd64                  1.0.2f-2                          amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
```

lsof related to nginx

```
lsof 2>/dev/null |grep -i libssl|grep nginx
nginx     17928              root  mem       REG              251,0    430560    2884885 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.2
nginx     17929          www-data  mem       REG              251,0    430560    2884885 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.2
nginx     17930          www-data  mem       REG              251,0    430560    2884885 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.2
nginx     17932          www-data  mem       REG              251,0    430560    2884885 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.2
nginx     17933          www-data  mem       REG              251,0    430560    2884885 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.2
```

Comment: Have you installed the [relevant updates](https://www.debian.org/security/2016/dsa-3566.en.html)?

Comment: Show the output of `dpkg -l | grep nginx`.

Comment: ...and the output of `dpkg -l | grep openssl`.

Comment: done. I use the usual debian and debian security repositories plus testing/sid with a negative pin.

Comment: Which `SSL / TLS` protocols are you using?

Comment: ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

Comment: 1.) Could you show the output of `dpkg -l | grep libssl`? 2.) Please ping me via @gf_, otherwise I won't get notified.

Comment: @gf_ added the output.

Comment: 1.) Could you show the output of `lsof | grep -i libssl`? 2.) Could you show your nginx config you're testing against; omit sensitive data if needed.

Comment: @gf_: added to question. Config or full lsof would be too much, as the (autogenerated) config is quite long and the full lsof contains descriptors from some lxc jails (and i.e. resolved to wrong PIDs / UIDs on the host). I think the "how it should be" is more useful than the current "that's how it is" state.

Comment: 1.) The used `libssl` is out of `stretch`, right? Did you try to run `nginx` with `libssl` out of `jessie`? 2.) Are you using `ssl_ciphers` in your `nginx` config? If so, could you show the directive?

Comment: Wait, this is strange. the 1.0.0 is from jessie and the 1.0.2 doesn't have any source here (according to ``apt-cache policy``). Let's see if the package can be removed and a standard distro package be used.

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it.

I installed `certbot` from debian unstable, which installed `1.0.2f-2`. unstable is pinned to priority "-100" (do not install from unstable unless requested with `-t unstable`). This means the version is between the jessie version `1.0.0X-Y` and the current unstable version `1.0.2.h-1`. This prevented an upgrade to the next version in unstable, while the upgrade in stable is an "older" version with respect to the version number.

Answer (score 2):

Installing the necessary updates ( as suggested by https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton in the comments ) seems to fix the issue for me.

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: See the accepted (self-)answer. The problem was, that a system with mixed stable/testing/unstable branches and the openssl versioning scheme never installed a fixed version, because the installed old testing-version has a version number higher than the to-be-installed stable-version. And the system was configured only to install testing/unstable packages (and upgrades) if explicitly specified.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on a Debian Wheezy Server. https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ always showed that my server was vulnerable to `CVE-2016-2107`. Other servers ,with (in my opinion) same config, did not have this security issue.

openssl, apache, php - all the same versions and same config.

After some investigation i found out that `mod_spdy` was installed and activated on this particular server.

After uninstalling `mod_spdy` the issue was solved.

```
dpkg -r mod-spdy-beta 
dpkg -P mod-spdy-beta
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593257/how-do-i-remove-spdy-mod-spdy